# Open Firefox iMacro From Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, firefox, imacros

I'm trying to open an iMacro from the mac terminal. I have the following:
    open -a Firefox imacros://run/?m=#Current.iim

This however tries to read the link as a file on my computer. Is there anyway to say that this is a link and not a file. If I run imacros://run/?m=#Current.iim right on the browser it works fine.